# Config Sass to output to a different folder in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I'm in need of your knowledge and help, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm currently using Ionic 3. I have an example.scss currently at src/theme/example.scss.

I know that I need to override webpack's config, so I copied webpack.config.js and sass.config.js to /config at my proyect's root folder.

I need to specifically 'tell' webpack to compile src/theme/example.scss to build/example.scss

I've read a lot about webpack, but I can't seem to find how to make it compile an specific file to a specific folder. Is it posible?

Hope you guys can help me!

My webpack.config.js

```js
/*
 * The webpack config exports an object that has a valid webpack configuration
 * For each environment name. By default, there are two Ionic environments:
 * "dev" and "prod". As such, the webpack.config.js exports a dictionary object
 * with "keys" for "dev" and "prod", where the value is a valid webpack configuration
 * For details on configuring webpack, see their documentation here
 * https://webpack.js.org/configuration/
 */

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ionicWebpackFactory = require(process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_FACTORY);

var ModuleConcatPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/ModuleConcatenationPlugin');
var PurifyPlugin = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer').PurifyPlugin;

var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var optimizedProdLoaders = [
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loader: [
      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_CACHE_LOADER
      },

      {
        loader: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true
        }
      },

      {
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getProdLoaders() {
  if (process.env.IONIC_OPTIMIZE_JS === 'true') {
    return optimizedProdLoaders;
  }
  return devConfig.module.loaders;
}

var devConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: process.env.IONIC_WEBPACK_LOADER
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};

var prodConfig = {
  entry: process.env.IONIC_APP_ENTRY_POINT,
  output: {
    path: '{{BUILD}}',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: ionicWebpackFactory.getSourceMapperFunction(),
  },
  devtool: process.env.IONIC_SOURCE_MAP_TYPE,

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    modules: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: getProdLoaders()
  },

  plugins: [
    ionicWebpackFactory.getIonicEnvironmentPlugin(),
    ionicWebpackFactory.getCommonChunksPlugin(),
    new ModuleConcatPlugin(),
    new PurifyPlugin()
  ],

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};


module.exports = {
  dev: devConfig,
  prod: prodConfig
}
```

Comment: post your webpack config file.

Comment: @MatheusSilva done!